# Is there anyway to cheat Firewall which is blocking my load-scripts.php file from Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, .htaccess

well i have a problem for which i can't find a proper solution. Since on my business PC firewall is blocking load-scripts.php i can't use my Wordpress properly (all jQuery part is not working: editor, selectboxes etc.). It shows with 403 error on inspector (if i put this load-scripts.php file with GET parameters in browser's address bar, it show dialog that this address is blocked by a firewall).

The file looks like this and it is suspicious for our Enterprise Firewall:

```
load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,thickbox,underscore,shortcode,media-upload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-tabs,mediaelem&load%5B%5D=ent,wp-mediaelement,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-a&load%5B%5D=uth-check,jquery-ui-resizable,jquery-ui-draggable,jquery-ui-button,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-dialog&ver=4.4.2
```

Is there any way i can cheat firewall? I thought about re-writing with htaccess this file but i have no clue how should i do it. Do you know e how i can manage that? Is there any way on resolving that?

Comment: If the answer to this was 'yes' it wouldn't be a very good firewall, would it.

Comment: Did you try load this content using $.get ?

Comment: With $.get? What do you mean?